# Prevent zsh's time command from giving output of program

Tags: shell, zsh

With zsh on my Terminal,

```
time hello.out
```

gives

```
Hello World

user    0.002
system  0.003
total   0.006
```

I have configured my .zshrc file with the following:

```
  TIMEFMT=$'\nuser\t%*U\nsystem\t%*S\ntotal\t%*E'
```

But I don't want the output of the program, namely

```
Hello World
```

to appear. What can I do to achieve this?

Lastly, the shell that Vim uses does not seem to remember the configuration I put in .zshrc, it uses the default format instead (giving "hello.out" as well as CPU info). What can I do to make the shell in Vim conform to the format I put in the file?

Comment: Redirect stdout: `time xxx > /dev/null`. Please don't ask more than 1 question per thread.

Comment: @D4RIO this works, but I would like this to occur for all arguments xxx, which means I probably need to modify my zsh init file. What should I include in the file?